# Customized Scoring function for OneVsRestClassifier in Pipeline

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, multiclass-classification, gridsearchcv

Im trying to create my own scoring function for a OneVsRestClassifier and am facing some issues.

```
    pipeline = Pipeline([
                ('tfidf', TfidfVectorizer()),
                ('clf', OneVsRestClassifier(MultinomialNB(fit_prior=True, class_prior=None)))
            ])

parameters = {
                'tfidf__max_df': (0.25, 0.5, 0.75),
                'tfidf__ngram_range': [(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3)],
                'clf__estimator__alpha': (1e-2, 1e-3)
            }
    grid_search_cv = GridSearchCV(pipeline, parameters, cv=2, n_jobs=3, verbose=10, scoring=overall_f1_score_cv)
    grid_search_cv.fit(train_X, train_y)
```

Here train_X and train_y are pandas DataFrames with train_X having just 1 column (containing text data) and train_y having 27 binary columns (27 different classes)
My scoring function is defined as below. I noticed that the predicted output was a np.array.

```
def overall_f1_score(y_actual, y_predict):
    num_genres = y_actual.shape[1]
    tp, fp, fn = 0, 0, 0
    for idx in range(num_genres):
        tp+=((y_actual[:,idx]==1) & (y_predict[:,idx]==1)).sum()
        fp+=((y_actual[:,idx]==0) & (y_predict[:,idx]==1)).sum()
        fn+=((y_actual[:,idx]==1) & (y_predict[:,idx]==0)).sum()
    precision = tp/(tp+fp)
    recall = tp/(tp+fn)
    f1_score = 2*precision*recall/(precision+recall)
    return f1_score

overall_f1_score_cv = make_scorer(overall_f1_score, greater_is_better=True)
```

Using the above scoring function, my GridSearchCV fit seems to get stuck. It works fine without my additional scoring argument. Can anyone please help me with the right format to use customized scoring function for this scenario?

Comment: Without the actual data to reproduce this, its hard to say. But ,when doing multi-class classification in scikit, never use a 2-d binary array for `y`. It is used as a label indicator matrix and turns on multi-label classification. In `OneVsRestClassifier`, that starts the Binary Relevance method which may select two or more classes (labels) as output, which you may not want.

Comment: Always use a single dimension `y` (with all possible classes into that single array) for multiclass. Something like : `[1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 4, 5, 1, 3, 4]` or `['cat', 'dog', 'horse', 'dog', 'horse', 'dog', 'cat']` etc

Comment: Thanks for your response, Vivek. Right...this is a multi-label classification. Hence, i have a 2d binary array...with more than one column (output) having 1 for several observations.